# Error launching UWP app for first time after Windows Update applied

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP app that has been stable for ages.  Last night Windows Update was applied and since then the app won't launch:

> The program has exited with code -1073741502 (0xc0000142) 'DLL
> Initialization Failed'.
> Activation of the Windows Store app failed
> with error 'The target process aborted before activation completed.
> Activation of the Windows Store app failed with error 'The app didn't
> start'.

The above is from running it in Visual Studio.

I have no idea where to even start with this, apart from thinking it might be something to do with the app's Universal Windows targets vs what the OS now supports?

Comment: It's hard to locate where the issue is just based on the information. Could you please tell me what is the Windows Update applied to your device? Do you have test the app on other devices with the same OS version?

Comment: I have other UWP apps that still work ok on the laptop, so I will look for differences. The code base is also somewhat old so I will try upgrading to target a more contemporary target and see how that goes.

Comment: Relevant patches:
2022-08 Cumulative Update for Windows 11 for x64-based Systems (KB5016629)
2022-08 Security Update for Windows 11 for x64-based Systems (KB5012170)

Comment: Does the app work on other devices that installed the same patch?